# Gravar campo DateTime nulo na base Access (mdb)

Tags: c#, datetime, microsoft-access, null

Boa tarde a todos.

Por favor preciso da ajuda de vocês.

Estou tentando gravar/atualizar um campo Nascimento do tipo DateTime, mas nem sempre esse campo será preenchido, devido a regra de negócio algumas vezes ele estará null.

A base utilizada é o Access formato mdb.

No momento de gravar/atualizar não estou conseguindo, vejam como estou fazendo.:

Exemplo:

```
public DateTime? Nascimento { get; set; }

cmdInsercao.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NASCIMENTO", Cli.Nascimento);
```

Tentei isto:

```
cmdInsercao.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NASCIMENTO", Cli.Nascimento == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : Cli.Nascimento);
```

e nada....

`DBNull.Value` não rolou também..

Alguém tem uma solução

Obrigado

Comment: Mas o que aconteceu?

Comment: Boa noite Ricardo. A Excpetion é : {"Tipo de dados incompatível na expressão de critério."}.